# Calling VBScript from WIX CustomActionTag and handling return

Tags: vbscript, wix, custom-action

I am new to WIX installer. i am trying to perform the following,
At the end of the InstallExecuteSequence i want to invoke a VBScript that does some blokcing of ports on windows firewall(i have written a script for that already).
Now if the operation is successful then installation continues else
A error is shown to the user on the installer and a option is given to the user to continue or abort.

Also before the script runs i want to give the user a option whether to do the "port related work"

i am currently doing ,

```
<CustomAction Id="DoSomething"
          BinaryKey="MyCA"
          VBScriptCall="Main"
          Execute="deferred"
          Return="check"
          HideTarget="no"
          Impersonate="no" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="DoSomething" Before="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

My question is how do i get the control back from the VBScript then display the message and option to the user ?

Comment: Are you aware that WiX has built-in support for this? You could just use the WiX FirewallException feature.

Comment: @PhilDW The firewallexception feature lets me create an exception for a (allows a)particular port. i am looking to block a particular port at the end of the installation script. Hence the question.

Comment: The MSI architecture wants you to collect user input in the UI sequence at the start of the install in such a way that it can be specified as a property on a command line for a silent install. There really isn't a good way to ask for input in the execute sequence because that's not where you show UI, so the decision to do the port work and rollback if it fails is a UI choice at the beginning. When your script runs use a condition based on the UI input property as a condition and similarly if it runs and fails return a failure result from the CA and the install will roll back.